# Securing routes in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.NET WebApi 2 for a REST interface to an ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

I am using Forms Auth for authentication.

My question is what is the best approach to secure WebApi routes that take parameters in the context of different users.

Example: A customer can access this example route to view an order.

```
http://host/api/customer/order/{orderId}
```

But what about when another customer that does not have access to that order comes along and tries to hit the same endpoint?

Also, I want the services to be able to be used by an admin that would have access to any order id.

Answer (score 3):

First you should have your API secure by default. In your WebAPI Config file add this line.

```
config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

It will apply the [Authorize] attribute to all of you API endpoints. This way you won't forget to secure an API.

If you want to all anonymous users to be able to use an endpoint, use the [AllowAnonymous] attribute like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("register")]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] RegistrationModel model)
{
}
```

If the user isn't signed in the filter will automatically be given a 401 error if you don't have the AllowAnonymous attribute.

For the case of someone trying to access an {orderId} that they shouldn't have permission for, I would just simply use claims based authorization within the method call. Something like this:

```
[Route("getProtectedThing")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
   var order = getOrder(orderId);
   if(ClaimsPrinciple.Current.Claims.First(x => x.Type == ClaimsTypes.NameIdentifier).Value 
        == order.memberId || 
        ClaimsPrinciple.Current.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "IsAdmin").Value)
   {
      return Ok("data");
   }
   return Unauthorized();
}
```

I hope this answers the question. I'm pretty sure you could do the claims checking before you hit the method with a filter. But I've never needed something so general in my apps.

Here is some [good documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api) on security in WebApi. It has some stuff on using attributes to block users by role and just other general information on authorization in WebAPI.

Comment: Where does `orderId.memberId` come from?

Comment: Sorry, I just made that up out of whole cloth. I was assuming that you would call a backend service to get the order, and that on that order you would have some sort of property to denote ownership that you could match with the user's claims.